# Python Remote Debugging with Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have the following set up:

- A Linux machine that have python code I want to run and launch the debug server
- A Windows machine that have Pycharm installed, I want to connect to the Linux machine above to debug my code

What should I do to on the Linux machine and how to start the debug server there?  (Noted: I can not installed pycharm on that machine)

Comment: Please see my response to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124213/python-pycharm-connect-to-remote-server/34167391#34167391

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - PyCharm connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124213/python-pycharm-connect-to-remote-server)