# Python - PyCharm connect to remote server

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed PyCharm 5.0.1 and want to connect it to remote host. there is manual on:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/remote-host-tool-window.html

but on two following suggested flows, some options do not exist:

View -> Tool Windows -> Remote Host (Remote Host do not exist)
Tools -> Deployment -> Browse Remote Host (Deployment do not exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/03/feature-spotlight-python-remote-development-with-pycharm/

"Remote development functionality is only available in PyCharm Professional Edition. For more details please see the editions comparison page."